# How can I trust a library in R?

Tags: r

Is there a way to see how many times a library has been downloaded in R? Or how many issues there have been. My concern is the lack of security around R libraries.

Comment: I would be careful with just using number of downloads, a reliable package that is new might have few downloads so it would be good to check other metrics as well as stated in one of the answers below.

Comment: If you're seriously concerned with security, there are companies such as Mango Solutions that will sell you sets of R packages that they have validated ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a package called [riskmetric](https://www.pharmar.org/risk/) specifically for estimating the 'trustworthyness' of other packages.

If you just want the number of downloads, you can use [cranlogs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cranlogs/index.html).

Comment: But how do I know if the `riskmetric` package is reliable ...?  :-)

Comment: You run it on itself!

Answer (score 1):

To check the total downloads for a package on `CRAN` use,

https://cranlogs.r-pkg.org/badges/grand-total/pkgname

Replace `pkgname` with the `CRAN` package name